# Upload image and show it on template - Django 2.0

Tags: python, django, jinja2

I have this code on my template:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
<div style="padding:40px;margin:40px;border:1px solid #ccc">
    <h1>picture</h1>
    <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> <!--{% url 'imageupload' %}-->
        {% csrf_token %} {{form}} 
        <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
    </form>
{% for img in images %}
    {{forloop.counter}}.<a href="{{ img.pic.url }}">{{ img.pic.name }}</a>
    ({{img.upload_date}})<hr />
{% endfor %}
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

Although I have doubts with the `form action` but anyways.

The problem is that when I click on `submit` button, it takes me to a blank page, no pop-up to actually upload the image, nothing.

Is there some example I should follow to accomplish this?

Also, this is just a proof test, but I'd like to know if a model and/or form is actually needed for it to work?

**EDIT**

Okay, by editing the `input` line like this `<input type="file" name='input_name' />` it actually opens the file pop-up, but obviously it doesn't upload anything, it needs like a `submit` button or something, so, now it looks like this:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
<div style="padding:40px;margin:40px;border:1px solid #ccc">
    <h1>picture</h1>
    <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> <!--{% url 'imageupload' %} -->
        {% csrf_token %} {{form}} 
        <input type="file" name='input_name' />
        <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
    </form>
{% for img in images %}
    {{forloop.counter}}.<a href="{{ img.pic.url }}">{{ img.pic.name }}</a>
    ({{img.upload_date}})<hr />
{% endfor %}
```

{% endblock content %}

But when I click on submit, it keeps sending me to a blank page, so, the value on submit, which is `Upload`, comes from this model:

```
from django.db import models
from django.forms import ModelForm

class Upload(models.Model):
    pic = models.FileField(upload_to="static/")    
    upload_date=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add =True)

class UploadForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Upload
        fields = ('pic',)
```

And on my views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from uploader.models import UploadForm,Upload
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.urls import reverse

def home(request):
    if request.method=="POST":
        img = UploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES)       
        if img.is_valid():
            img.save()  
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('imageupload'))
    else:
        img=UploadForm()
    images=Upload.objects.all()
    return render(request,'image_upload.html',{'form':img,'images':images})
```

And in my urls.py:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib import admin
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from django.views import defaults as default_views
from uploader import views as uploader_views

urlpatterns = [...
    some patterns...
    url(r'^image_upload/', uploader_views.home, name='imageupload'),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: This is will never open a window to let you upload file, but instead `<input type='file' >` Where is your `forms.py`?

Comment: Thank You, exactly, do I need a forms.py even for a tiny example?

Comment: Not really. you can use `<input type='file' name='input_name' >`

Comment: Hmmm Okay, so the submit comes later and it should work with my models.py, that's part of the issue, should I update my question or just open a new one? Thank You

Comment: You retrieve the field with the `input_name`,  update your question

Comment: Edited, if You need further clarification please let me know, Thank You very much

Comment: Maybe it's the fact that I don't have any form, Idk

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171410/discussion-between-lemayzeur-and-neove).